# Restrict Objective-C format string to only object specifiers

Tags: objective-c

I'd like to make an Objective-C method ([like this one](https://github.com/cocodelabs/NSAttributedString-CCLFormat/blob/master/NSAttributedStringFormat/NSAttributedString%2BCCLFormat.m#L133)) that accepts a format string that only allows object specifiers `%@`. Is it possible to use the [`format` `__attribute__`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) to perform static checks on my format strings to ensure they don't violate this restriction?

Comment: 1) Don't add irrelevant tags. Objective-C is not C. 2) `__attribute__` is not standard.

Comment: The `format` `__attribute__` can apply to `C` as well, so I thought there might be some knowledge overlap. I don't think it's irrelevant.

Comment: Point is, it is not part of the C standard either. It is implementation specific!

Comment: I get that. Should I tag it with `gcc` and `clang` then?

Comment: Why do you need a format string?

Comment: I want to boldify objects that are printed in my string with an `NSAttributrsString`